# making variables in event listener to use in seprate if statment

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 inputs that a user must fill out to unlock the submit button. Once the inputs are filled out correctly it removes the disabled attribute from the submit button. Also I thought using let would make it a global var?:

```
{
  let emailunlock = false;//this cant be seen unless I add it below
}
```

Im assuming it dont work because its not a global variable, is there a way to use the above code to turn it into one. So that the IF and statement can see it? without modify the code too much? or am i doing something else wrong? im assuming this should be enough code its javascript

```
document.getElementById("cinfo").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var phoneInput = document.getElementById('cinfo').value;
  var phoneno = /^\(?([1]{1})?[(-. )]?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if (phoneInput.match(phoneno)) {
    document.getElementById("req").innerHTML = "Thank You";
    let phoneunlock = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("req").innerHTML = "Amost Done";
    let phoneunlock = false;

  }
});

document.getElementById("emailinput").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var emailInput = document.getElementById('emailinput').value;
  var emailpat = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (emailInput.match(emailpat)) {
    document.getElementById("reqqq").innerHTML = "Thank You";
    let emailunlock = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("reqqq").innerHTML = "Amost Done";
    let emailunlock = false;
  }
});

var emailunlock = true; // want to remove this and let the above event listener dictate the values
var phoneunlock = true; //I want to remove this and let the above event listener dictate the values

document.getElementById("cinfo").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (phoneunlock && emailunlock) {
    alert('yes it did');
    document.getElementById('saveForm').removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    console.log('nope not yet');
    document.getElementById('saveForm').setAttribute("disabled", null);
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `let` if you want to assign to the global variable. That makes it a local variable.

Comment: I'm also curious: Why do you use `var` when you declare `emailInput`, but `let` when you declare `emailunlock`? Maybe you have a misunderstanding of the difference between them?

Comment: they where all var at first then i tried using let on some

Comment: But the correct solution is not to use either, since you just want to assign the variable, not declare a new variable.

Comment: At the top of the code outside of the functions, declare the variables with a default value of false using `let`. Then inside of the functions themselves, get rid of `let`. This will allow the value of the variables to be edited and accessed globally.  The reason for setting the default value to false, is onload, they are all invalid, so they are false

Comment: Why don't just declare the variables on the top and then don't use let for every single time you set the variables.

Answer (score 1):

your code should look something like this

```
let emailunlock = false;
let phoneunlock = false;

document.getElementById("cinfo").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var phoneInput = document.getElementById('cinfo').value;
  var phoneno = /^\(?([1]{1})?[(-. )]?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if (phoneInput.match(phoneno)) {
    document.getElementById("req").innerHTML = "Thank You";
    phoneunlock = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("req").innerHTML = "Amost Done";
    phoneunlock = false;

  }
});

document.getElementById("emailinput").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var emailInput = document.getElementById('emailinput').value;
  var emailpat = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (emailInput.match(emailpat)) {
    document.getElementById("reqqq").innerHTML = "Thank You";
    emailunlock = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("reqqq").innerHTML = "Amost Done";
    emailunlock = false;
  }
});

document.getElementById("cinfo").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (phoneunlock && emailunlock) {
    alert('yes it did');
    document.getElementById('saveForm').removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    console.log('nope not yet');
    document.getElementById('saveForm').setAttribute("disabled", null);
  }
});
```

you have to move your variable declaration somewhere before the functions using those, and don't use "let" or "var" before assigning new values to your variable as that will redeclare it and that declaration will only be accessible inside that function only.